# Forces between electron, neutron and proton

Tags: forces, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, atoms

What are the forces between a proton and another proton? I think they are electromagnetic, gravitational and nuclear.

Forces between proton and electron? I think, electromagnetic, gravitational and nuclear again.

Between neutron and proton? I think there won't be any electromagnetic force here, but gravitational and nuclear will be present. Same for neutron and electron?

Between neutron and neutron only nuclear and gravitational.

Between two electrons? Will there be nuclear? I think electrostatic and gravitational will exist.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: you do not indicate in your profile your background in physics. The question has inherent misunderstandings. see https://www.britannica.com/science/subatomic-particle/Four-basic-forces

Comment: @annav I am a university student, sorry for not having it in my profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q:What are the forces between a proton and another proton?

An: Nuclear $α_{s}=1$

Q:Forces between proton and electron?

An: Electromagnetic $α=1/137$

Q:Between neutron and proton?

An: Nuclear $α_{s}=1$

Q:Between neutron and neutron?

An: Nuclear $α_{s}=1$
(nuclear forces are independent from electromagnetic charge)

Q:Between two electrons?

An: Electromagnetic $α=1/137$

Gravity is everywhere in all cases but negligible $α_{g}=10^{-39}$ in quantum scale.

For quarks and leptons there is also the weak interaction that changes the flavor of the particles but also can cause attraction or repulsion. The coupling constant of this force is $α_{w}=10^{-6}$.

The larger the coupling constant $a$ (in the case of the electromagnetic force it is referred as Fine Structure Constant) the stronger the related force.

Comment: you should stress it is the dominant  contribution you are describing (quarks are charged after all)

Comment: @annav Yes you are right. At the end of the day these are all the same EM force, their range and curl are the only things that actually differentiates them. Strong force for example has a range in the order of less than one fm.